# UILabel expand UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm facing many problems with auto layout in xCode. One of them is trying to make a `UILabel` resizable and expand a `UICollectionViewCell` to show its entire dynamic content (that has multiple lines). I have already tried [this tutorial](https://possiblemobile.com/2016/02/sizing-uicollectionviewcell-fit-multiline-uilabel/) but i get this error in console.

> the item width must be less than the width of the UICollectionView minus the section insets left and right values, minus the content insets left and right values.

I've already set the constraints of my UILabel.

Any idea of how can I accomplish that?

This is how y UICollectionView looks like

[image: UICollectoinView]